# SQL Running total with duplicated column

Tags: sql, database

I have this solution

```
SELECT
    CAST(TO_CHAR(FirstApprovalDate, 'YYYYMM') AS Int) AS MonthYear,
    COUNT(DISTINCT name) OVER (ORDER BY CAST(TO_CHAR(FirstApprovalDate, 'YYYYMM') AS Int) ASC) AS running_total
FROM 
    MP_Data.Solution
WHERE
    Published = 1 AND Hub <> 'pd'
ORDER BY
    CAST(TO_CHAR(FirstApprovalDate, 'YYYYMM') AS Int) DESC
```

This is the output I get:

```
MonthYear   running_total
-------------------------
202308  811
202308  811
202308  811
202308  811
202308  811
202308  811
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202307  805
202306  787
```

etc

Is it possible to cut duplicated rows from the `monthYear` column when `FirstApprovalDate` is date time column like 2023-08-09 20:51:19?

Comment: You could just add the keyword DISTINCT after SELECT - ie. SELECT DISTINCT CAST(TO_CHAR( ... etc.).  Otherwise, do a search on using GROUP BY, as you would also be able to achieved your desired result by grouping on the "MonthYear" value

Comment: Wow, so simple. DISTINCT works. I spent like a couple hours staring at it trying to figure it out. Thank you so much! Is a shame that i can`t upvote your comment

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not the right way to do this, you want `GROUP BY CAST(TO_CHAR(FirstApprovalDate, 'YYYYMM') AS Int)`

Comment: Thanks for the response but no DISTINCT is the right in my case. When i use GROUP function, data rendered wrong. Like so. Numbers have to be bigger

202308 64
202307 63
202306 62
202305 61
202304 60
202303 59
202302 58